# GWT - AbsolutePanel and ProvidesResize + RequiresResize

Tags: gwt

I tried to implement [ProvidesResize](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html) interface to [com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbsolutePanel.html). Then I implemented RequiresResize to its supposed childs but it seems like method onResize() fails to be called or I didn't get it :(

So my question is... How to catch was an AbsolutePanel child widget resized or not and is it possible to?

P.S.
GWT 2.2/2.3

Comment: I also done almost same situation, like re-sizing with its parent absolute panel by setting child widget position style relative OR by setting its width and height 100%.

Comment: 'done' means succeeded? If 'yes' please share some tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your panel itself could implement the `RequiresResize` interface and have the `onResize()` method do something like this (copied from [DeckLayoutPanel](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckLayoutPanel.java#200)):

```java
  public void onResize() {
    for (Widget child : getChildren()) {
      if (child instanceof RequiresResize) {
        ((RequiresResize) child).onResize();
      }
    }
  }
```

Now if you make your panel a child of a `ProvidesResize` widget, the chain of onResize() calls should propagate through your panel to the children of your panel.

Comment: you mean the AbsolutePanel should implement RequiresResize interface because onResize() method is in RequiresResize  only or both ? Could you show a detailed code snippet(s)

Comment: I found that in DeckLayoutPanel onResize() method is been invoked by forceLayout() method :S So here I am not pretty sure what is the equivalent in AbsolutePanel then?

Comment: If your class which extends `AbsolutePanel` and implements `ProvidesResize` also implements `RequiresResize` then when it is made a child of another `ProvidesResize` panel its onResize() method will be called and will in turn result in calling onResize() of the children of your panel, if implemented like the code snippet above.

Comment: No, I mean how to invoke the onResize() in AbsolutePanel? The DeckLayoutPanel is using  forceLayout() method for that :S But what about the AbsolutePanel ? I couldn't find the forceLayout() method in AbsolutePanel or there is an equivalent method though?

Comment: The `onResize()` method in the DeckLayoutPanel is public and so would be called by any `ProvidesResize` parent as well. See Riley Lark's answer for a clarification on the relationship between resize-notifying panels, which will perhaps make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML just doesn't tell you when something changes size.  Major bummer.

What you CAN find out is when the window changes size.  `RootLayoutPanel` listens for window size change events.  When it hears one, it tells all its children, "Hey, you probably just changed size.  Check it out."  Then all of those children are supposed to tell all of THEIR children, "Hey, check your size, guys.  Might be different."

So.  Your `AbsolutePanel` that implements `ProvidesResize` has to be hooked into this process somehow.  If you add it to `RootLayoutPanel`, you can get the message by *also* implementing `RequiresResize`.  If you're not adding it into the `RootLayoutPanel` chain, you have to find out resize information yourself somehow.  You could either listen for window size events, or trigger the size calculation when you know something else changed in the layout.  Whatever you want.  Unfortunately this can't be done for you unless you have a continuous chain of `RequiresResize` and `ProvidesResize` widgets all the way up to `RootLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simillar to [this](http://code.google.com/p/multi-platform/source/browse/trunk/library.gwt_client.GWT_UI/src/library/gwt_client/gwt_ui/widget_factory/flow_panel/FlowLayoutPanel.java?r=506)